# How to calculate measurement error in an exponentially non-linear sensor? (self made pressure sensor)

Tags: sensor, thermistor, error, calibration, accuracy

I'm trying to calculate the measurement error from a home-made pressure sensor which I have in a voltage divider circuit. It has the same negative exponential non-linear resistance characteristics as an NTC thermistor: with increasing force [N] the resistance [ohms] decreases non-linearly. The pressure sensor acts as a variable resistor, and I am measuring the voltage drop across it using an 8bit ADC.

So far, I have taken resistance measurements (with a multimeter accuracy to .1 ohm) of the homemade velostat pressure sensor at exerted forces from 1 to 10 N using a force gauge (with an accuracy of 0.05N), with 5 resistance measurements at each force value. The average of the 5 measurements are graphed below.

My plan to calculate the exerted force [N] is to use a "power function" which is created from the data in Excel and rearrange it to solve for X (force) at a certain Y (resistance). The resistance (Y) is derived from the voltage measured by the ADC.

Is this a good approach, or should I use a lookup table or linear interpolation? (I'm not sure on how to do either of these yet.)

How do I calculate the measurement error from the sensor seeing as resistance changes only a small amount in higher force ranges, and resistance changes a lot (sensitive) at small exerted force ranges?

[image]

[image]

EDIT: added chart of my resistance measurements with max and min values graphed (the 20 measurements at each value of F [N] not shown in table).

[image]

[image]

Comment: You already found an equivalent function, doesn't it fulfill you requirements?

Comment: What makes you think that the **accuracy** of your meter is 0.1 ohm? Is it possible that you are interpreting the **resolution** to be the accuracy?

Comment: you assume an exponential model, and that might be very fine – but I could fit arbitrary functions to your measurement points. How do you know it's exponential? Does that come from physics?

Comment: @MarcusMüller He doesn't have his correlation on there, but it would be close to 1.  It would be hard to come up with an arbitrary function that fits that data set that good.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat A third-degree polynomial would not fit this just as well? I'd be suprised! This exponential fit has three free parameters just as well: an offset, a prefactor and a scale.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I doubt it would correlate as well and it would look very weird.  If it looks like a duck.....

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat as a communications engineer: if it looks like a duck from 10 datapoints, you go and prepare for an elephant fading channel

Comment: @ElliotAlderson yes i did mean resolution instead of accuracy, sorry for the mix up.

Comment: @MarcusMüller this is the first time im doing this (finding an equation for a sensor), as described i recorded data and then in excel found that the power function trendline best fit the averaged data, the polynomial functions only started to fit well after the 4th degree, what is the normal procedure when finding an equation for a sensor? in this guide for a force sensitive resistor (https://www.generationrobots.com/media/FSR400-Series-Integration-Guide.pdf) in chapter 7.0 it says curve must be modelled to the "look up table" data, do you have literature/links on this, how to derive equation?

Comment: @BetweenBeltSizes95 ah! well, then you have a curve that you want to approximate – so you do exactly that; you define an acceptable error and find a function that's easy to interpolate that approximates your reference curve within that error bound. If your exponential does that, very well! I'd just probably try to divide the curve into segments of roughly equivalent slope, and then do a piecewise linear representation, which is computationally very easy, and can be made arbitrarily accurate by increasing the number of segments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$V_2=V_{ref}\dfrac{R_t}{R_1+R_t}=V_{ref}(\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{R_1}{R_t}})$$

$$V_2=V_{ref}(\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{R_1}{244.5x^{-0.941}}})$$

$$R_t=\dfrac{R_1}{\dfrac{V_{ref}}{V_2}-1}$$

$$244.5x^{-0.941}=\dfrac{R_1}{\dfrac{V_{ref}}{V_2}-1}$$

$$x^{-0.941}=\dfrac{R_1}{244.5(\dfrac{V_{ref}}{V_2}-1)}$$

$$-0.941\cdot lnx=ln\dfrac{R_1}{244.5(\dfrac{V_{ref}}{V_2}-1)}$$

$$x=e^(\dfrac{ln\dfrac{R_1}{244.5(\dfrac{V_{ref}}{V_2}-1)}}{-0.941})$$

$$x=\left( \dfrac{R_1}{244.5(\dfrac{V_{ref}}{V_2}-1)} \right) ^\dfrac{1}{-0.941}$$

You can now use the measurements and write the function into partial Taylor series.

$${\displaystyle x_{approx} = f(V_a)+{\frac {f'(V_a)}{1!}}(V_2-V_a)+{\frac {f''(V_a)}{2!}}(V_2-V_a)^{2}+{\frac {f'''(V_a)}{3!}}(V_2-V_a)^{3}+\cdots ,}$$

For each measurement point a, you calculate the 1 to n-th differential (additional LUT table, with fixed numbers) and then you calculate the interpolated value. Using just 1st derivative could be just fine, with 2nd derivative the measurement error will be greater than approximation error, 3rd derivative is an overkill.

If you have some MATLAB, Octave,...you could solve the derivations and calculate numbers. Then you use those pre-calculated values with regard of your calibration points. The only overhead to the CPU is then squaring the (V2-Va).

You could expand/modify the Taylor series for two neighboring points. [link](https://dspace.library.uu.nl/bitstream/1874/580/16/c4.pdf)

EDIT:

I have searched the net for some symbolic differentiation. First of all in the school books you will usually find a function defined as y=f(x) so lets rearrange

y=(R_1/(244.45*(V_R/x-1)))^(1/-0.941)

where y is the Force, and x is the measured voltage

I have inserted the equation (R_1/(244.45*(V_R/x-1)))^(1/-0.941) into an online solver - [www.derivative-calculator.net](https://www.derivative-calculator.net/). I have chosen the values Vref=3.3V, R1=220 ohm.

[image]

I did compute the voltage V2 according to equation (1) when Rt=130, according to your graph (function equivalent) it should be at force=2.

V2=3.3* 130/(220+130) = 1,225V

I got this:

[image]

The force should be approx. 2, I don't know why is this deviation. The solver also made an simplification of the function:

$$\dfrac{4889^\frac{1000}{941}\left(\frac{V_{ref}}{x}-1\right)^\frac{1000}{941}}{20^\frac{1000}{941}R_1^\frac{1000}{941}}$$

Finally, the 1st derivative is:
$$-\dfrac{50{\cdot}4889^\frac{1000}{941}V_{ref}\left(\frac{V_{ref}}{x}-1\right)^\frac{59}{941}}{941{\cdot}20^\frac{59}{941}R_1^\frac{1000}{941}x^2}$$

Now all you have to do is to insert values.

For example 1st point (F=1; Rt=230), V2=3.3*230/(220+230)= 1.686V. I do insert this value as x, and the value of the 1st derivative is f'(1.686)= -1.37612. The second derivative is 1.737047.

[image]

For the small deviation around the 1st point the force could be computed as Taylor series of 2nd order:

$$F_{approx} = 1 - 1.37612\cdot (V_2-1.686V)+0.68806\cdot (V_2-1.686V)^2$$

Calculating the V2 for the 2nd point (F=2; Rt=135) as already before V2=1.225 and inserting into above equation gives F=1.78

Comment: Your last \$x=\dots\$ equation can be simplified.

Comment: @jonk I didn't spend time for simplifications, if you want to, you are welcome to edit.

Comment: I do these all the time, so it's kind of built-in to my psyche. Since \$\ln\left(A^B\right) = B\,\ln\left(A\right)\$ it follows that \$\exp\left(B\,\ln\left(A\right)\right)=A^B\$. I was thinking along those lines. That's all.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you are using a Taylor series? Truncating it will not give you a good polynomial approximation. If the OP wants a polynomial of degree \$n\$ to relate the measured voltage \$V_2\$ and the measured force it is better to just do a polynomial fit, which will reduce the error of the approximation.

Comment: @jDAQ Taylor was the first in my mind, since the function and its derivatives are known. What polynomial would fit in your opinion better than the function itself?

Comment: @jonk I did, what you said - in the way I understood. It would take longer time for me to revive knowledge in the logarithm functions

Comment: I suggest actually doing a polynomial fit of the experimental data https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/polyfit.html and looking at how it correlates with the measurements. It will allow the OP to choose the polynomial degree and also minimize the error.

Comment: @jDAQ I don't think you can use Polyfit function in a low end MCU.My proposal is to calculate up to 2nd order (two squaring), while your approach would take N-th order, N is the LUT points number.

Comment: I see, I didn't know the OP was planning to have an MCU do the data fit, since he said "My plan to calculate ... created from the data in Excel". I thought he was going to do a calibration, generate the Polyfit in his computer and then use the resulting polynomial to write some code with it. And if he is actually going to use a computer, even for a 2nd order polynomial the fit will beat (or equal) the Taylor series (regarding the squared-error). And for low-order polynomials it would be possible to fit a simplified Polyfit code in the MCU too github.com/Rotario/arduinoCurveFitting

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Thank you for your help, i have never learned or derived an equation for a sensor before, and wanted to know if my approach generally was ok and otherwise what the "normal" way to derive an equation for a sensor would be? All i did was measure the R at different Force levels and found the trendline in excel which best fit the average data line so i could then get an equation. Without excel i wouldn't know how to start, other than making a linear line and getting a y = mx+b equation (thats my level of knowledge). Do you have any link/literature that could help? many thanks!

Comment: @BetweenBeltSizes95 Have you seen the edit?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič i have seen your edit, Thank you. I have a question though, why not simply use the formula y=(R_1/(244.45*(V_R/x-1)))^(1/-0.941) ? The taylor series gives more accurate results? I dont remember how to do taylor series and what its used for. If i simply use the formula you made above, how would i go about finding my measurement error from the calculated value? (i have not added the min and max R values for the 5 resistance measurements at each value of F).

Comment: @MarkoBuršič i have added the graph with my range of resistances measured (the max and min), if i use the simple equation you made: y=(R_1/(244.45*(V_R/x-1)))^(1/-0.941) how would i go about calculating the measurement error? like +/- N ? The Graph still does not include uncertainties in the multimeter resistance measurement (0.1 ohm) and the force measurement uncertainty ( 0.05N)